# How to add Table Of Content in a PDF file (internal one)?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, indexing

So I have an OyO (Thalia) which can read PDF files. It have an option "Table of content". It shows several labels which direct on certain pages for example when opening "64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf".

I think this is accomplished by some internal Table Of Content structure inside PDF files.

How can I make a custom one? I'm using Libre Office writer and have exported an PDF file from it.

I've tried adding bookmarks inside Libre Office writer but when I export to PDF with the option "Export bookmarks" - nothing is then displayed on my OyO "Table of content" option (when I copy the file).

I also tried downloading the Adobe Acrobat DC trail version if that could work but it's downloading me some OS X installation and I can't change that. But even if I could - will Wine run it?

Any help please?

Comment: You need to add a PDF index/table of contents, not bookmarks. See https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Creating_a_Table_of_Contents

Comment: @muru This doesn't help me. I don't have "Indexes and Tables " in my insert tab.

Comment: Perhaps upgrade to a new version of LibreOffice? This PPA has it: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-5-1